# Step-by-step installation Bittorrent-Bencode module (python)?

Tags: python

I am new in Python and bencode and couldn't figure out how to install BitTorrent Bencode package. I altready installed setuptools and pip from python repository.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What OS are you using?